# NetworkOnMyThreadExcepion inside new Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, postgresql, exception

I need to connect to postgreSQL. When I try to run this code I got exception caused by: NetworkOnMyThreadExcepion. I've made new Thread, but it's still same problem.

```
...
final ErrorFragment error = new ErrorFragment();
...

new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        /* Properties prop, String url*/
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop);
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    error.setArguments(exceptionToBundle(e));
                    error.show(getFragmentManager(), "tagError");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}).run();

...
private Bundle exceptionToBundle(Exception e){
...
}
```

Comment: use `start()` instead of `run()`

Answer (score 0):

As @tyczj already mentioned, you have to use `start()` to start the `Thread`. `run()` is the method which will be executed in the new `Thread`. If you call `run()` directly you run your code on the current `Thread`.

So instead of this:

```
new Thread(...).run();
```

try this:

```
new Thread(...).start();
```

Comment: Yes, it was that. Now it's work.